# PostBuild events are not run on AppHarbor?

Tags: build, appharbor

I've got a postbuild event that is executed just fine locally, but not on AppHarbor:

> ```
>  <PostBuildEvent>
>   if not exist "$(TargetDir)NativeBinaries" md "$(TargetDir)NativeBinaries" 
>   xcopy /s /y /i "$(SolutionDir)packages\LibGit2Sharp.0.8\NativeBinaries\x86\*.*" "$(TargetDir)NativeBinaries\x86" 
>   xcopy /s /y /i"$(SolutionDir)packages\LibGit2Sharp.0.8\NativeBinaries\amd64\*.*" "$(TargetDir)NativeBinaries\amd64"
>   </PostBuildEvent>
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postbuild events are executed as part of the AppHarbor build process. For particulars on why your build may be failing, please see the [related AppHarbor support discussion](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/1110-build-failed-but-no-errors-in-the-detailed-log).